# C fprintf hexadecimal incorrect output

Tags: c, file, file-io, printf

I have a char array composed of hex values that looks similar to this:

```
 char str[] =
        "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
        "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
        "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff";
```

After manipulating this string, I want to `fprintf` this string to a file using this statement:

`fprintf(fp, "%X\n", str);`

but I'm getting an output similar to this:

```
65C58A20
```

Seems like it got condensed to a single hex number. How can I `fprintf` the `str` in the same form I declared it above, with separate hex values for each individual byte?

Comment: Might `sprintf()` work? Use it to convert the char array to a string, then print out that string to file instead?

Comment: Why `%X`?! Did you read the manual for `printf`?

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "%02X\n", (unsigned char)str[index]);`

Comment: @KerrekSB, I tried %s but the ascii didn't seem to be working, just got a bunch of boxes.

Comment: hint: your code puts hex EB into the location str[0]

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: See my updated answer. I'm assuming you want to print the same textual representation that was part of your source code back out as a string (as opposed to writing the actual bytes that are *described* by your source code).

Comment: Suggest editing `"\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff` --> `"\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff";`  (add last 2 characters, if that is what you meant.

Comment: What you're doing is (non-portably) printing the address (or part of the address) of `str`.  What you need to be doing is printing each byte of the content of `str` — that requires a loop, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof str - 1; ++i)
    fprintf(fp, "\\x%02x", (unsigned char)str[i]);
```